# Pass data to another input on page load

Tags: jquery

I am using following to pass data from one input to another:

```
    $('#totalcom').change(function() {
    $('#firsttot').val($(this).val());
});
```

If it is possible I want to pass data not on change, but on load. There will be value in the input and when page will load I want this value was passed to another input.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Kind of difficult to understand your question. Your select is going to have data on load that you want to automatically pass to the textbox?

Comment: Yes, I want the value was passed automatically when website page will load. Not when i change the input

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/5j1256bd/

Answer (score 0):

Listen to `document` ready instead of `#totalcom` change:

```js
$(document).ready(function (event) {
  $('#firsttot').val($('#totalcom').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label><code>#totalcom:</code> <input id="totalcom" value="Some default value"></label><br>
<label><code>#firsttot:</code> <input id="firsttot"></label>
```